# Slick embed condition in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, slick

I'm looking for a clean way to embed a condition right into a slick SQL
Is there a better way to do :

```
val sqlPart = if(myCondition) {
  """INNER JOIN otherthing r ON r.id=t.id_otherthing WHERE r.field=value"""
} else """WHERE 1=1"""

sql"""
SELECT 1 FROM #$table t
#$sqlPart
AND t.field2=value2
"""
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be dynamic? Often that is a result of a bad table design. maybe we can assist changing it

Comment: you can use IF statments in SQL (most dialects) https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms182717(v=sql.120).aspx. Please the DBMS you are using, a correct can depend on it

Comment: hmm I could probably add the condition in the query yes good point